# Why is XMonad's Prompt not working for me?

Tags: haskell, window-managers, xmonad

So my MWE xmonad.hs is as follows:

```
import XMonad

import XMonad.Prompt
import XMonad.Prompt.Shell

import XMonad.Util.EZConfig

myKeys =
  [ ("M-s", shellPrompt def)
  , ("M-<Return>", spawn "/usr/bin/alacritty")
  , ("M-q", kill)
  , ("M1-r", spawn "xmonad --recompile && xmonad --restart")
  ]

main = do
  xmonad $ def
         { modMask = mod4Mask
         } `additionalKeysP` myKeys
```

The key bindings work except for

```
("M-s", shellPrompt def)
```

With another [config](https://gitlab.com/dwt1/dotfiles/-/blob/master/.xmonad/xmonad.hs) i tried it works as expected but I can not figure out, what's wrong with my MWE above (obviously it compiles just fine). Also I already have a config I am rather content with so I would prefer implementing prompts in my own config instead of trimming down the linked one.

System: Arch Linux

```
~ $ pacman -Qi xmonad | grep Version
Version                  : 0.15-72
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Please let me know if you require additional info. Thank you!

EDIT 1:
I added two more key bindings to the mwe:

```
, ("M-S-e"     , spawn $ "xdotool text 'test'")
, ("M-S-w"     , spawn $ "xdotool key Cotrol_L+F4")
```

neither of them works, just like the prompt (`xdotool` is installed). So there might be a connection?
I have also tried to use the standard syntax for key bindings without using `XMonad.Util.EZConfig` to no avail.

Comment: Replace `shellPrompt def` with `spawn "/usr/bin/alacritty"` to see if, the issue is the keybinding or `shellPrompt def`.

Comment: The keybinding works. I did as suggested and alacritty opend just fine.

Comment: My guess would be it's showing up - just very small in one of the corners of you screen. Instead of passing `def` you could pass the `dtXPConfig` which is defined in the config you linked (you will also need to copy that definition to your own config).

Comment: Still no dice. Also the window that has focus remains focused when I hit "M-s"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmonad#Broken/missing_XMonad.Prompt_and_window_decorations) ArchWiki link sent me on the right path solve my problem.

The problem seems to be caused by missing fonts on the system that the xmonad prompt expects.

Excerpt:

> Broken/missing XMonad.Prompt and window decorations
>
> XMonad by default uses the font -misc-fixed-*-*-*-*-10-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
> [5]. If this font is missing those windows simply fail to render at
> all. Easiest fix is to install xorg-fonts-misc.

I am actually running Gentoo 5.4.80 and my solution was to install the `x11-base/xorg-x11` package.